# Upgrade iPhone 5 from iOS 7.0.4 to iOS 7.1.2

Tags: ios, upgrade, iphone

I have an iPhone 5 that I use with Straight Talk (telecom provider) and I am trying to "upgrade" it from 7.0.4 to 7.1.2, or any release with the 7.x version for that matter.

I specifically do not want to upgrade to IOS 8 just yet.

I have the file "iPhone5,2_7.1.2_11D257_Restore.ipsw" but I get the error "The device isn't eligible for the requested build." I've also hashed out the gs.apple address in my hosts file.

I know you can't downgrade from 8 to 7, but in this case is there a way I can still upgrade to a later version of 7.x?

Comment: Do you need to be 'online' when trying to update? If not, you can go offline on both devices (Mac and iPhone) connect your iPhone to iTunes and use the ipsw image.

Comment: How would that get round it not being signed?

Comment: That I do not know. I have no experience with this. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Apple have stopped signing any iOS 7 for any device that can run iOS 8.

As far as I am aware, you have no other choices than to stay on 7.0.4 or go to 8.0.2